# xarray nearest N points

Tags: python, gis, netcdf, python-xarray

I know I can extract the value for the nearest lat/long to my input

```
import xarray

ds = xarray.open_dataset('/path/to/netcdf.nc')
single_val = ds['Band1'].sel(longitude=target_long,
                             latitude=target_lat,
                             method='nearest')
```

But is there a way to quickly pull out an arbitrary number of values from the nearest N points? Like if I wanted to pull the 9 closest points (3 x 3 grid) for a given lat/long.

I realize I can covert the `xarray.core.dataset.Dataset`, `ds`, to a dataframe, and then manually calculate distance and pull out an average for 9 closest points, but calculating distance is the rate-limiting step. Is there a faster way?

```
from vincenty import vincenty

# convert to dataframe
df = ds['Band1'].to_dataframe()
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)  # set 'latitude' and 'longitude' columns

# calculate distance from my lat/long to all lat/longs in the dataframe
# this is the step I want to avoid, can take a very long time ~20+ mins for my data
df['distance'] = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].apply(lambda latlong: vincenty(latlong,
                                                                              (target_lat, target_long)),
                                                     axis=1)

# sort by closest points
df2.sort_values(by='distance', ascending=True, inplace=True)

# get nearest 9 points and calculate average 
avg_vals = df2['Band1'].loc[range(9)].mean()
```

Comment: What about popping out each value after you get the nearest, then calling the nearest on the next one?

Comment: E.g. pt1 = pt0.nearest. Remove pt0 from list. pt2=pt1.nearest. Remove pt1 from list. etc.